# Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: software-installation

I tried to install popcorn-time but I can't do it.

```
~$ cd Prejemi
~/Prejemi$ ls
Popcorn-Time  PopcornTime-latest.exe  Popcorn-Time-linux32.tar.gz
~/Prejemi$ cd Popcorn-Time/
~/Prejemi/Popcorn-Time$ ls
libffmpegsumo.so  nw.pak  package.nw  Popcorn-Time
~/Prejemi/Popcorn-Time$ ./Popcorn-Time
./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libXtst.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: You could have just copied the output of the command into your question, instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Create a link:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libXtst.so.6.1.0 libXtst.so.6
```

if you have version 6.1.0. If not, change the version number in the second command.